# Referencing angular function outside of scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code roughly. How can I access myFunction() outside of the angular code? Help is greatly appreciated. ng-click isn't working with the DOM manipulation I am doing, but ng-repeat isn't working as I would like. I can get onclick events to work within the generated content.

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngTable']).controller('x', function ($scope, $filter, $http, $q, ngTableParams, $window) {

    var myFunction = function(){
        some angular stuff
    }

}

//javascript
function testFunction(){
    angular.element(document.getElementById('x')).scope().myFunction();
}
```

The above code is what I have found from searching and does not work as I would like. Giving the error in console: Cannot read property 'myFunction' of undefined

edit: Here is the DOM manipulation I'm doing... myFunction has id as an argument being passed in my actual implementation.

```
usersArray[] //populated object array with name and id

$scope.generateUsers = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < usersArray.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += "<div ng-click='myFunction(" + usersArray[i].id + ")'> usersArray[i].name + "</div><br />";
    }
}
```

SOLUTION:

in the javascript function if I changed my code to:

```
function testFunction(supUserId) {
    angular.element(document.getElementById('HTMLElementId')).scope().myFunction();
}
```

Changing the element from the controller (x in my case) to an HTML element in the body of my page worked.

Comment: Maybe a better idea would be to share what DOM manipulation a you are doing to see if we can get my-click working

Comment: First thing to assess is why you are doing this in the first place? Most likely you need a directive but not much detail has been provided. There is almost never a need to use `onclick`. Please show your ng-repeat that isn't working. Important to understand that ng-repeat creates child scope for each item

Comment: I have edited it to show the content I am generating in JS.

Answer (score 1):

myfunction is not declared inside scope. May be add ur myfunction inside like code below

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngTable']).controller('x', 
function ($scope, $filter, $http, $q, ngTableParams, $window) {
    $scope.myFunction = function(){
        some angular stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I made the change and it still does not work. Console error: Cannot read property 'myFunction' of undefined.